# uncaught TypeError TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'send')

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Whenever my bot is added to a discord server it crashes. This is the code I use for the guild join message:

```js
client.on('guildCreate', guild => {
    const exampleEmbed = {
        color: 0x0099ff,
        title: 'Some title',
        url: 'https://discord.js.org',
        author: {
            name: 'Some name',
            icon_url: 'https://i.imgur.com/AfFp7pu.png',
            url: 'https://discord.js.org',
        },
        description: 'Some description here',
        thumbnail: {
            url: 'https://i.imgur.com/AfFp7pu.png',
        },
        fields: [
            {
                name: 'Regular field title',
                value: 'Some value here',
            },
            {
                name: '\u200b',
                value: '\u200b',
                inline: false,
            },
            {
                name: 'Inline field title',
                value: 'Some value here',
                inline: true,
            },
            {
                name: 'Inline field title',
                value: 'Some value here',
                inline: true,
            },
            {
                name: 'Inline field title',
                value: 'Some value here',
                inline: true,
            },
        ],
        image: {
            url: 'https://i.imgur.com/AfFp7pu.png',
        },
        timestamp: new Date(),
        footer: {
            text: 'Some footer text here',
            icon_url: 'https://i.imgur.com/AfFp7pu.png',
        },
    };

    guild.systemChannel.send({ embeds: [exampleEmbed] });
});
```

Does anyone know how I can fix the code to make it work (embed is an example from [discord.js](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/embeds.html#using-an-embed-object) that should work)

Answer (score 0):

If you [check the documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=systemChannel), you can see that `systemChannel` can be `null` so you'll need to check it first.

Another option is to check if there is a channel with the name `general` and send it there:

```js
// ...

if (guild.systemChannel)
  return guild.systemChannel.send({ embeds: [exampleEmbed] });

let channel = guild.channels.cache.find(
  (ch) => ch.name.toLowerCase() === 'general'
);

if (channel)
  return channel.send({ embeds: [exampleEmbed] });

// ...
```